# Why is my has_child filter treating an AND as an OR in ES 1.5?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get only branches that have inspections greater than a certain value and within a certain radius.

Below is my query, but instead of doing as above it returns branches that meet either of the conditions. What am I not missing? Thanks!

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": { }
        },
        "filter": {
            "has_child": {
                "type": "inspections",
                "query": {
                    "filtered": {
                        "query": {
                            "match_all": { }
                        },
                        "filter": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "range": {
                                        "geolocations.count": {
                                            "gte": 15
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "geo_distance": {
                                        "distance": "1km",
                                        "geolocations.loc": {
                                            "lat": "29.139963",
                                            "lon": "-98.905306"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show a document that matches while it shouldn't?

Comment: Thank you, I managed to figure it out. My fault for just jumping around the documentation when I'm new to ES, and making assumptions. What I needed to do was query with has child and then have a nested query for the property I wanted to check by. Will see if this should be filters instead, but pasting the query here to help others:


{"query":{"has_child":{"type":"inspections","query":{"nested":{"path":"geolocations","filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"geolocations.count":{"gte":13}}},{"geo_distance":{"distance":"42mi","geolocations.loc":{"lat":"29.139963","lon":"-98.905306"}}}]}}}}}}}